# Is there any TIMEOUT for cURL calls or Symfony2 task execution?

Tags: php, symfony, curl, symfony-2.6

I'm just try to find is there is any `TIMEOUT` or `MAX EXECUTION TIME` for execute Symfony2 tasks. Why? Any time I execute the task `pdone:sync` it stop with this log:

```
Symfony > pdone:sync

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Notice: Undefined offset: 2000

pdone:sync
The command terminated with an error status (1)
```

This is my code which is called from task as a service and second SOQL query returns exactly 6911 items so it should insert 6911 and not stop at 2000, why? what is happening there? Any advice or help or ideas?

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class SyncController extends Controller
{
    private $_em;
    private $_container;
    private $_rs;

    public function __construct(Container $container, EntityManager $em, RequestStack $rs)
    {
        $this->_container = $container;
        $this->_em = $em;
        $this->_rs = $rs;
    }

    public function syncVeevaData()
    {
        $em = $this->_em;
        $request = $this->_rs->getCurrentRequest();
        $container = $this->_container;

        // Will need this in the whole function so lets declare it here
        $now = new \DateTime();

        $expireTime = clone $now;
        $expireTime = $expireTime->modify('+1 week');

        // Request veeva token and instance URL
        $token_url = $container->getParameter('login_uri')."/services/oauth2/token";

        $params = "grant_type=".$container->getParameter('grant_type')
            ."&client_id=".$container->getParameter('client_id')
            ."&username=".$container->getParameter('veeva_username')
            ."&password=".$container->getParameter('veeva_password')
            ."&client_secret=".$container->getParameter('client_secret')
            ."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($container->getParameter('redirect_uri'));

        $curl = curl_init($token_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

        $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($status != 200) {
            $respObj['error'] = "Error: call to token URL $token_url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error ".curl_error(
                    $curl
                ).", curl_errno ".curl_errno($curl);

            return $respObj;
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

        $veevaToken = $respObj['access_token'] = $response['access_token'];
        $instanceUrl = $respObj['instance_url'] = $response['instance_url'];

        if (!isset($veevaToken) || $veevaToken == "") {
            $respObj['error'] = "Error - access token missing from response!";

            return $respObj;
        }

        if (!isset($instanceUrl) || $instanceUrl == "") {
            $respObj['error'] = "Error - instance URL missing from response!";

            return $respObj;
        }

        // Request reps and sync against DB
        $soqlQuery1 = "SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Username,Email,LastModifiedDate FROM User";
        $soqlUrl1 = $instanceUrl.'/services/data/v28.0/query/?q='.urlencode($soqlQuery1);

        $curl = curl_init($soqlUrl1);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: OAuth $veevaToken"));

        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($curl);

        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($status != 200) {
            $respObj['error'] = "Error: call to token URL $token_url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error ".curl_error(
                    $curl
                ).", curl_errno ".curl_errno($curl);

            return $respObj;
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        $soqlObj1 = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $soqlObj1['totalSize']; $i++) {
            $entReps = $em->getRepository('PDOneBundle:Representative')->findOneBy(
                array(
                    'veeva_rep_id' => $soqlObj1['records'][$i]['Id'],
                )
            );

            if (!$entReps) {
                // if there is no reps, then we add
                $newReps = new Entity\Representative();

                // we set the values from veeva
                $newReps->setVeevaRepId($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['Id']);
                $newReps->setEmail($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['Email']);
                $newReps->setFirst($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['FirstName']);
                $newReps->setLast($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['LastName']);
                $newReps->setUsername($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['Username']);
                $newReps->setLastLoginAt($now);
                $newReps->setLastSyncAt($now);
                $newReps->setDisplayName(
                    $soqlObj1['records'][$i]['FirstName'].' '.$soqlObj1['records'][$i]['LastName']
                );
                $newReps->setRepType("VEEVA");

                $em->persist($newReps);
                $em->flush();

                // Put new reps into $newRepsArr
                $repsArr[$newReps->getId()] = $newReps->getVeevaRepId();
            } else {
                $lastModifiedDate = new \DateTime(
                    $soqlObj1['records'][$i]['LastModifiedDate']
                );

                if ($lastModifiedDate > $entReps->getLastSyncAt()) {
                    // obtained a reps, we update its data
                    $entReps->setEmail($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['Email']);
                    $entReps->setFirst($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['FirstName']);
                    $entReps->setLast($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['LastName']);
                    $entReps->setUsername($soqlObj1['records'][$i]['Username']);
                    $entReps->setLastLoginAt($now);
                    $entReps->setLastSyncAt($now);
                    $entReps->setDisplayName(
                        $soqlObj1['records'][$i]['FirstName'].' '.$soqlObj1['records'][$i]['LastName']
                    );
                    $entReps->setRepType("VEEVA");

                    // Put updated reps into $updRepsArr
                    $repsArr[$entReps->getId()] = $entReps->getVeevaRepId();
                }
            }
        }

        $em->flush();

        // Get territories and sync against DB
        $soqlQuery2 = "SELECT Id,Name,LastModifiedDate FROM Territory";
        $soqlUrl2 = $instanceUrl.'/services/data/v28.0/query/?q='.urlencode($soqlQuery2);

        $curl = curl_init($soqlUrl2);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: OAuth $veevaToken"));

        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($curl);

        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($status != 200) {
            $respObj['error'] = "Error: call to token URL $token_url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error ".curl_error(
                    $curl
                ).", curl_errno ".curl_errno($curl);

            return $respObj;
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        $soqlObj2 = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $soqlObj2['totalSize']; $i++) {
            $entTerritory = $em->getRepository('PDOneBundle:Territory')->findOneBy(
                array(
                    'veeva_territory_id' => $soqlObj2['records'][$i]['Id']
                )
            );

            if (!$entTerritory) {
                // if there is no territory, then we add
                $newTerritory = new Entity\Territory();

                // we set the values from veeva
                if ($soqlObj2['records'][$i]['Id'] !== null || $soqlObj2['records'][$i]['Id'] !== "") {
                    $newTerritory->setVeevaTerritoryId($soqlObj2['records'][$i]['Id']);
                    $newTerritory->setName($soqlObj2['records'][$i]['Name']);

                    $em->persist($newTerritory);
                    $em->flush();
                }

                $terrArr[] = $newTerritory->getId();
                $terrFailArr[] = $soqlObj2['records'][$i]['Name'];
            } else {
                $lastModifiedDate = new \DateTime(
                    $soqlObj2['records'][$i]['LastModifiedDate']
                );

                if ($lastModifiedDate > $entTerritory->getUpdatedAt()) {
                    // obtained a territory, we update its data
                    $entTerritory->setName($soqlObj2['records'][0]['Name']);
                }

                $terrArr[] = $entTerritory->getId();
            }
        }

        $em->flush();

        return $respObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, there are 2 issues with your current implementation, 
1. With too much cUrl request and database migration, request timeout will kill your process. => You should consider running it with a CLI.
2. You shouldn't flush your entityManager each time in loop (neither flush all at once) => Maybe flush db at every 50-100 entities.

Comment: @Tuannguyen I am using from CLI (notice this: this is my code which is called from task) and I am moved to batch insert every 500 entities but issue still. There are only two cURL request and that is not the issue since I got the results the issue is in another place but I just can't find it.